# Codeigniter $this->input->post() empty while $_POST is working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

On a codeigniter installation, I am trying to use the inbuilt `$this->input->post('some_data')` function, however `$this->input->post()` is an empty array.

A `print_r($_POST)` gives all the variables fully and correctly?

According to the codeigniter docs, The input class "is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually", leaving me wondering what else I'm meant to do.

Any thoughts on how I should try to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on a regular form or are you using AJAX?

Comment: Just a regular form at the moment

Comment: what does var_dump($this->input->post());  show?

Comment: Do you want to get all post data as an array, without any specific `key` or your `$this->input->post('some_data')` is not working ?

Comment: Matthew - please post your controller and view code.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution jet?

Answer (score 30):

You can check, if your view looks something like this (correct):

```
<form method="post" action="/controller/submit/">
```

vs (doesn't work):

```
<form method="post" action="/controller/submit">
```

Second one here is incorrect, because it redirects without carrying over post variables.

**Explanation:**

When url doesn't have slash in the end, it means that this points to a file.

Now, when web server looks up the file, it sees, that this is really a directory and sends a redirect to the browser with a slash in the end.

Browser makes new query to the new URL with slash, but doesn't post the form contents. That's where the form contents are lost.

Comment: I was about to ask you what to do in a similar problem but using XMLHttpRequest.

//wont work
    xhr.open("POST","/controller/doRegistration",true);

//doing as you said... wont work
    xhr.open("POST","/controller/doRegistration/",true);

//but... works
    xhr.open("POST",'/controller/doRegistration',true);

Comment: @Sobiaholic Yes!
Now im using something like 
website.com/index.php/controller/index
website.com/index.php/controller/catalog
and that kind of things.

Comment: I hate to say that using '/index.php/controller/catalog' is doing ok. Not "/index.php/controller/catalog". Honestly dont know why. Between .httpaccess file and apostrophe '' Im confused.

Comment: both 1st and second are sme WTF

Comment: @rahultyagi They are not the same - first one has slash in the end. I added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

To use `$this->input->post()`  initialize the form helper. You could do that by default in config.

Answer (score 5):

Try This, change

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite.cl/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mywebsite.cl/';
```

Some provider auto add www , https , etc to your url, most of the times, this causes this issue

Comment: OK. This was actually my case! Thanks for the insight! I've recently added ssl to the website and the base_url was without www but my htaccess was forcing no www! :/

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading from 2.2.x to 3.0.x -- reason post method fails.
If you are upgrading CI 3.x, need to keep the index_page in config file. 
Also check the .htaccess file for mod_rewrite. [CI_3.x](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html)

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; // ci 2.x
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; // ci 3.x
```

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can look for help solve this.

1. Has anything changed or been extended in the core CodeIgniter files. Check that `system/core/Input.php` is an original copy and the contents of `application/library` and `application/core` for additional files
2. Do the other input methods work? What is the result of this when run beside your `print_r` call?

   `echo $this->input->user_agent();`
3. What data is output from `print_r`? Look in `application/config/config.php` for the line `$config['global_xss_filtering']`. Is this set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`? If `TRUE` maybe the cross site scripting filter has a problem with the data you're posting (this is unlikely I think)

Comment: When asking for clarification and diagnostics from the OP, use post comments under the question (you shouldn't be asking any questions in an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var_dump($this->input->post());
```

Please see the screen shot.
[Here I am priniting all the post array value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9xJ2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change your form action,

From this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>yourprocess">
```

Into this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/yourprocess">
```

Basically, you just need to add "index.php" after your base_url():

> action="http://www.yourdomain.com/**index.php**/yourprocess"

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with an ajax call. I was using this:

`type: 'posts',`

instead of

`type: 'post',`

Syntax, D'oh!

Comment: This is an entirely different issue because the OP says **`print_r($_POST)` gives all the variables fully and correctly**.  I would invite you to post your own new question and answer it, but Typo questions are closed as off-topic on StackOverflow.  This post should be removed as it is not focused on resolving the issue that the OP was having.  Just because the title is vague doesn't mean that all possible failures receiving posted data should be stuffed into this page.  Dear moderators, do not trash this comment as rude -- this is truth and is aimed at improving site content.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I was POSTing to the CodeIgniter website via an outdated Python script and that script was using "http" URLs instead of "https". I had updated the website to use only https a while ago, but this script wasn't updated.

In short, using HTTP caused `$this->input->post()` to be an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the parent constructor.
When your controller is loaded you must
Call the parent CI_Controller class constructor in your controller constructor

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that `$this->input->post()` does not support getting all POST data, only specific data, for example `$this->input->post('my_post_var').` This is why `var_dump($this->input->post());` is empty.

A few solutions, stick to $_POST for retrieving all POST data, or assign variables from each POST item that you need, for example:

```
// variables will be false if not post data exists
$var_1 = $this->input->post('my_post_var_1');
$var_2 = $this->input->post('my_post_var_2');
$var_3 = $this->input->post('my_post_var_3');
```

**However, since the above code is not very DRY, I like to do the following:**

```
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    // get all post data in one nice array
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
        $insert[$key] = $value;
    }
}
else
{
    // user hasen't submitted anything yet!
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is completely false.  From the docs regardting `$this->input->post()` - _"To return an array of all POST items call without any parameters."_ - what you're doing is completely unnecessary, and it also circumvents Codeigniter's built-in security measures.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score -2):

Finally got the issue resolved today. The issue was with the **`.htaccess`** file.

Learning to myself: [MUST READ THE CODEIGNITER DOCUMENTATION](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=htaccess) more thoroughly.

Answer (score -3):

To see all the post value try `var_dump($this->input->post(ALL));`

Answer (score -3):

Solved as follows:

Does the following exclude the redirection that is .htacess that will run the $ this-> input- > post ('name' ) on the controller, in my case it worked perfectly .

abs,
José Camargo]