# $this->input->post() is empty while $_POST is set in Codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, post

I am having an issue in codeigniter where I try to get form data sent via post in this form:

```
    <form action="http://localhost/Bookstore/index.php/cart/add/1" method="post">
        <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="http://localhost/Bookstore/index.php/book/id/1" class="hidden">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> In den Warenkorb
        </button>
    </form>
```

However, when I try to access `$this->input->post('url')`, `$this->input->post()` does not contain anything while `$_POST` contains the data i need (`url`).

Any ideas how to fix this? I would like to avoid using $_POST, because a have read it is not suggested in codeigniter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter $this->input->post() empty while $\_POST is working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376251/codeigniter-this-input-post-empty-while-post-is-working-correctly)

Comment: you can check that form helper is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did already try this but it didn't help.

Comment: I think this has something to do with `button` having the type submit, try to use an `input` element rather than `button` type and check.

Comment: How can i submit data via an input element? The url data is already held in an input field.

Comment: from the looks of your code your are trying to submit a hidden field? why not use input type hidden?

Comment: hm. i can try that. its a class from twitter bootstrap. but you could be true, its the only notable difference to other forms which work. I'll try that.

Comment: this doesn't do the trick either

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this in your config.php file in CI

```
 $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

And change the

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

in your config.php to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. The funny thing is, that some forms work, and others dont. But thanks anyway, really!

Comment: Are you using the latest CI version?If it's not get the latest version and check.For me it's working.

Comment: Yeah, i do. Its weird. I guess ill despereately try to reimplement the view/controller from scratch and see if this will work. but thats my last try, as i have implemented other views/controllers wich submit data via post where everything is perfectly fine. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to put exactly

```
action="/Bookstore/index.php/cart/add/1"
```

it should work.

for some reason i think **.htaccess** + **CI** controller config u need to put exactly that url