# How to acess the Data passed to a CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

Hi I am having trouble accessing the data I am posting to a CI Controller. the $id variable isn't assigned to anything. Is this the correct way to assign the post data to a variable in the Controller?

View/AngularJs

```
addanswers = function() {
    var id = $scope.idSelectedPoll;

    $http({
    url: 'polls/json_get_answers',
    method: "POST",
    datatype : "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({'id':id}),
    }).success(function (data) {
    $scope.answers = data;
    });


    }
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Polls extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

function index() {
$data['title'] = 'Poll Viewer';
$data['viewname'] = 'pollBrowser';
$data['scripts']['polls'] = 'polls';
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('polls/pollBrowser',$data, TRUE);

$this->load->helper('html');
$this->load->view('templates/master',$data);
}

function json_get_answers()

{    
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$this->load->model('Poll','poll');
$data = $this->poll->get_json_answers_data($id);
print json_encode($data);
}
}
```

Model

```
 <?php
class Poll extends CI_Model {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
 $this->load->database();
}
function get_json_answers_data($id) {
$this->db->from('Answers');
$this->db->where("answerSet",$id);
$this->db->order_by('id');
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
}
}
```

I've included an image of it sending the post data after clicking on an item in the list. Is this how it should look? Request Payload indicates that it seems to be posting the 'id' data correctly.

[image]

Comment: echo var_dump($_POST); and echo print_r($_POST); both say that the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if `id` is present in $_POST ?

If so, take a look at this post regarding [Codeigniter $this->input->post() empty while $_POST is working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376251/codeigniter-this-input-post-empty-while-post-is-working-correctly)

Comment: Hi I've enabled CSRF in config/config.php which has led me to this 'POST http://localhost:8000/index.php/polls/json_get_polls 500 (Internal Server Error)'. I think I should be able to work it out from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first try to `json_decode` the data

```
$data = json_decode($this->input->post());
$id = $data['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working there was an issue with the post call in the angularjs function, not entirely sure why the data needs to be sent like that or why the headers must be stated. If someone could explain the reasoning behind this answer that would appreciated. Thanks for the help guys!

```
addanswers = function() {
    var id = $scope.idSelectedPoll;

    $http({
    url: 'polls/json_get_answers',
    method: "POST",
    datatype : "json",
    data: 'id=' + id,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
    $scope.answers = data;
    });

    }
}
```