# Share date from angular controler to codeigniter controler

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

Can I use data from angular controller in Codeigniter controller? I need this array $scope.prosek. I want to use its data in my Codeigniter controller and submit it to database.

```
 var MojApp = angular.module("MojApp", []);

        MojApp.controller("SastojakCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.hrana = js_array;
            $scope.sastojci = [];
            $scope.ukupno = {kalorije : 0.0,proteini:0.0,uh:0.0,masti:0.0,kolicina:0.0};
            $scope.prosek = {kalorije : 0.0,proteini:0.0,uh:0.0,masti:0.0};
```

Comment: You can make a POST request of the data in `$scope.prosek` from your AngularJS controller to a route you define in Codeigniter. You can pick it up from the Controller for that route.

Comment: Could you show me an example of that.I am new to these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example you can build upon.

```js
var MojApp = angular.module("MojApp", []);

MojApp.controller("SastojakCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.prosek = {
    kalorije: 0.0,
    proteini: 0.0,
    uh: 0.0,
    masti: 0.0
  };
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '<api_host>/test/create/',
    data: $scope.prosek,
  }).then(function(res) {
    // do something with response from CI
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}]);
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body ng-app="MojApp">
  <div ng-controller="SastojakCtrl"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Register an endpoint in CodeIgniter `routes.php`. Say,

```
$routes['test/create'] = 'nutrition/create';
```

In the controller class,

```
class Nutrition extends CI_Controller {
  public function create() {
    $all = $this->input->post(); // this is data posted from the angular controller

  }

}
```

Comment: `input->post()` is probaby empty since `$http` sends `application/json` by default. Certainly didn't work in older codeigniter versions <3

Comment: It is empty so how can i make it not empty? :D

Comment: Make sure there is a forward slash appended to the request URL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16796532/5189811