# POST responses are null()

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I have reworked this a million ways and cant find why its null

leaving out the md5 hash and placing it inline
passing strings directly to function

login_view.php

```
<form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo site_url('login/auth'); ?>" method="post">
       <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
       <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>
       <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
       <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
       <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
       <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
           <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
         </label>
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Sign in</button>
     </form>
```

login.php

```
function auth(){
$email    = $this->input-> post('email');
$password = $this->input-> post('password');
$validate = $this->login_model->validate($email,$password);
```

cant retrieve POST items as normal

Comment: "leaving out the md5 hash" **DO NOT USE MD5 FOR PASSWORD HASHING.** It's highly insecure. Use https://www.php.net/password_hash and https://www.php.net/password_verify.

Comment: Are you certain that `login/auth` is being reached? How have you determined that the inputs are not being retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding slash after URL like this

```
<form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo site_url('login/auth/'); ?>" method="post">
```

If you still have issues check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376251/codeigniter-this-input-post-empty-while-post-is-working-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's your use of `site_url`, which should probably be `base_url()`.

According to the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html), `site_url` returns the index file which doesn't seem like what you need.